# javascriptserializer date format issue

Tags: json, datetime, javascriptserializer

I am serializing a complex object with lot of properties of other Types and Lists to JSON form but the issue is with DateTime properties. I get the epoch time with JavascriptSerializer (rather than mm/dd/YYYY).

Is there any way I can get the datetime in mm/dd/YYYY : HH.MM.SS form without modifying the class defination of the object i am serialzing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This cannot be achieved using `JavaScriptSerializer` and without modifying the underlying class. This could be achieved with [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution to this using the RegisterConverters method on the serializer object.

[Custom DateTime JSON Format for .NET JavaScriptSerializer](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/)

You just create a class that inherit JavaScriptConverter and implement your own serialization of the DateTime object.

And then serialize like this:

```
var obj = new { date = DateTime.Now };
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ser.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DateTimeJavaScriptConverter() });
var result = ser.Serialize(obj);
```

result = {"date":"2019-10-25T11:49:58.7322411Z"}

Change the line

```
return new CustomString(((DateTime)obj).ToUniversalTime().ToString("O"));
```

for your custom version of the DateTime.

The class from the link:

```
public class DateTimeJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType(dictionary, type);
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(obj is DateTime)) return null;
        return new CustomString(((DateTime)obj).ToUniversalTime().ToString("O"));
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
      get { return new[] { typeof(DateTime) }; }
    }

    private class CustomString : Uri, IDictionary<string, object>
    {
        public CustomString(string str)
          : base(str, UriKind.Relative)
        {
        }

        void IDictionary<string, object>.Add(string key, object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.ContainsKey(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        ICollection<string> IDictionary<string, object>.Keys
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.Remove(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        ICollection<object> IDictionary<string, object>.Values
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        object IDictionary<string, object>.this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Clear()
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        int ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Count
        {
          get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.IsReadOnly
        {
          get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```