# datetime field in json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, ssis, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a .json like this:

```
[
    {
        "number":"00000001",
        "dt_doc":"2019-09-26T17:39.000Z",
        "address":"complete address"
    }
]
```

But I've got problem with the field dt_doc, this is my deserialization code...
I have this in the main:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(Variables.JsonFilePath);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Testata> testata = js.Deserialize<List<Testata>>(jsonFileContent);
        foreach(Testata test in testata)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.number= test.number;
            Output0Buffer.dtdoc = test.dt_doc;
            Output0Buffer.address= test.address;
        }
    }
```

and in my class Testata.cs I have defined the field in this way:

```
public DateTime dt_doc { get; set; }
```

But I got an exception on this field, probably related to 8601 standard, is there any way to solve?

This is the exception:

> Error: System.FormatException: 2019-09-26T17:39.000Z it's not a valid value for DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: String not recognized as valid DateTime value.

Comment: It's not recommended to use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) class, switch to `Json.NET` instead. To do achieve it with `JavaScriptSerializer` you should create custom `JavaScriptConverter`, as it shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557998/4728685)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are missing seconds in date

```
"dt_doc":"2019-09-26T17:39.000Z"
```

should be

```
"dt_doc":"2019-09-26T17:39.00.000Z"
```

If this is intentional then you can specify the format. I have tried this using `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
public class Testata
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm.fffZ")]
    public DateTime dt_doc { get; set; }
}

public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}

List<Testata> testata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Testata>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: But OP is using `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for that.. i have updated the post mentioning the library I used.

Comment: I still get the exception I've added in the first post

Answer (score 0):

you could read it in your class as a string and then:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(test.dt_doc,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm.fffZ");
```

Comment: I've tried in this way, I got no exception but I can't see data field, just other fields but not this