# Jackson serialize and Deserialize DateTime From/To WCF DateTime

Tags: java, c#, json, jackson

I use `Jackson` to serialise and deserialise object. I have `.NET WCF DateTime JSON` format with `Time Zone`. And Jackson can't deserialise `JSON` to object. I found some solutions, but is there any `Jackson` embedded or suggested solution how to do that?

Example dates:

- "/Date(12345678989+0000)/"
- "/Date(12345678989-0000)/"

See also:
[How to parse .net DateTime received as json string into java's Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127529/how-to-parse-net-datetime-received-as-json-string-into-javas-date-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle date time in format generated by `.NET`'s [JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) in form `/Date(number of ticks)/` you need to implement custom deserialiser. To understand what are "ticks" lets take a look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Date object, represented in JSON as "/Date(number of ticks)/". The
>   number of ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates
>   the number of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01
>   January, 1970 UTC.
>
> The maximum supported date value is MaxValue (12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM)
>   and the minimum supported date value is MinValue (1/1/0001 12:00:00
>   AM).

I assume, that in your case you have an offset provided as well, like in examples.

Using `Java 8` `Time` package and above knowledge we can implement custom deserialiser as below plus example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputJson = "{\"date\":\"/Date(1583001930882+0100)/\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Epoch epoch = mapper.readValue(inputJson, Epoch.class);
        System.out.println(epoch.getDate());
    }
}

class Epoch {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = JavaScriptDateDeserializer.class)
    private OffsetDateTime date;

    public OffsetDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(OffsetDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

class JavaScriptDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private final Pattern JAVASCRIPT_DATE = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((-?\\d+)([+-]\\d+)\\)/");

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        Matcher matcher = JAVASCRIPT_DATE.matcher(value);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String epoch = matcher.group(1);
            String offset = matcher.group(2);

            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(epoch));

            return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.of(offset));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
2020-02-29T19:45:30.882+01:00
```

Serialiser could look like below:

```
class JavaScriptDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(OffsetDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(32);
        builder.append("/Date(");
        builder.append(value.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        if (!value.getOffset().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)) {
            builder.append(value.getOffset().toString());
        }
        builder.append(")/");

        gen.writeString(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

You need to handle Time Zone properly, if you always send/receive date in `UTC` you can skip this part.

See also:

- [WCF and JSON Date format](https://edspencer.me.uk/posts/2011-10-11-wcf-and-json-date-format/)
- [JavaScript's Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [Unix epoch time to Java Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object)
- [javascriptserializer date format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045710/javascriptserializer-date-format-issue)
- [Good (Date)Times with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net)
- [C# DateTime.Ticks equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706306/c-sharp-datetime-ticks-equivalent-in-java)

Comment: Hi Michal thanks for your sharing,also can you share sample for serialization thanks,I cant thouch .net part for that reason I need to add some custom serialization/deserilization attribute to my java project

Comment: @Bilgehan, take a look on updated answer. Generally, you need to convert your `date` object to `Instant` and get milliseconds from it. See [How to get milliseconds from LocalDateTime in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944370/how-to-get-milliseconds-from-localdatetime-in-java-8)